# How can I repeat Item labels in Google Sheets pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: screenshot]

The left side is what google sheets does.  The right side is what I want it to do.

This is is an attribute that can be done in Excel.  On Google product forums I found that it was mentioned in 2014, early 2016, and still has no helpful replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct solution for this:

1. In the Pivot Table Editor, go to Rows and check the option "Repeat Row Labels" at the bottom of the required item.

Comment: How can I do this for column labels?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is moderately simple

Add a new sheet.
On the pivot table sheet, step over a column so that you are outside the table, and enter the formula =Count(X:X) where X is the last column of the pivot table.  Count only counts cells with numeric data.  If you have strings, then I'd be interested in what you are pivoting.  There are other ways to find the last filled row, but this is the easiest.

New!A1 has the formula =Pivot!A1

Replicate across.

Modify the count cell to add whatever headers you have, usually 1.
Thus my G1 on the New sheet =Pivot!G1+1

Now

```
New!A2=if(row()<=$G$1,if(isblank(Pivot!A2),A1,Pivot!A2),"")
```

Replicate across, then down to cover the pivot table's dimensions, and enough extra to allow for future growth.

Break down of the command.  Explanation follow chunk.

```
=if(row()<=$G$1,
```

Compare the current row number to the max filled row on the pivot table

```
                if(isblank(Pivot!A2)
```

If the corresponding cell on the pivot table is blank

```
                                     ,A1,
```

Then copy the cell above.

```
                                         Pivot!A2),
```

Otherwise, copy the cell on the pivot table.

```
                                                    "")
```

Row() is too big, do nothing.