# How to make Pivot Table repeat row labels *without* expanding all columns?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I am making a spreadsheet for doing some analytics and determining win, lose, or draw percentages.  The pivot table is all fine, except that Column A is a date column, and if I choose to not have all the other columns expanded, Column A does not repeat the row labels despite being set to do so.  It looks like this:

[image: pivot table]

How can I get Sheets to repeat the Date Label for each row, without expanding all the items in the other columns?  Note that "Repeat Row Labels" is already enabled for all rows of the table, and works fine provided they are all expanded.  The issue here is that I don't want to have to expand them all, to get the repeated labels.

*to be clear* - I already have the option to repeat labels turned on.  This is a specific subtlety to pivot tables where the labels do not repeat, if all columns are not expanded.  This is *not* a duplicate question asking about how to turn on Repeat Row Labels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repeat Item labels in Google Sheets pivot table?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101716/how-can-i-repeat-item-labels-in-google-sheets-pivot-table)

Comment: Nope not at all... I already have that feature enabled.  This is a specific subtlety of pivot tables.  Appreciate the attempt though!